# Aziz of Complex Analysis

Tags: mathematics

Does anyone know about Prof. Abdul Aziz on whose name Aziz's theorem is named?

Aziz's theorem is a theorem about the location of zeros of polynomials.

Comment: @Nick, I don't think this is right. This is another Abdul Aziz from Kashmir (in South Asia). https://vidwan.inflibnet.ac.in/profile/22728 who seems to fit this theorem. He lists his expertise as "zeros of polynomials".

Comment: @M.Farooq My apologies.  I appear to have misread the information.

Comment: Yes, although I don't understand the entire scope of his work. But, I do know him for the wonderful person he is.

Answer (score 6):

As per the obituaries, the person behind Aziz's theorem is Prof. Aziz ul Azeem. He was a professor of mathematics at the University of Kashmir (located in South Asia). This is not another well known mathematics professor from Howard University, Abdul-Aziz Yakubu, (the name is quite similar). From the obituary of Prof. Azeem [News link](https://www.greaterkashmir.com/todays-paper/veteran-mathematician-prof-aziz-ul-azeem-demise-condoled)

> “Prof Aziz-ul-Azeem was a distinguished mathematician who contributed significantly to the growth and development of the university. His contributions will continue to serve as a guiding force for young scholars to draw inspiration from,” Prof Talat said. Prof Aziz-ul-Azeem was globally known for ‘Aziz Theorem’ while leading several path-breaking research projects in mathematics.

Answer (score 2):

Now that Professor Aziz is no more, I have written an obituary, a delayed one.

This obituary has appeared in several dailies.

[Kashmir Reader](https://kashmirreader.com/2021/12/02/professor-of-mathematics-abdul-aziz-a-delayed-eulogy/)

[Rising Kashmir](https://www.risingkashmir.com/-Professor-Abdul-Aziz-of-Mathematics--A-delayed-eulogy-96592)